# Encapsulate only comma-separated strings in quotes

Tags: bash, shell-script, csv, string

I have some data that is currently in TSV format, but needs to be converted into CSV format. The only problem is that occasionally in the TSV, there are some values that include commas that are not always in the same column (the number of commas per instance can vary as well). I want to encapsulate these comma-separated strings in quotes so that the CSV can parse correctly.

What I  have (TSV):

```
Freddy, Jasmine, and Lucy     412      Penguin
Maggie    5,432    salad
Joe       4        John Smith, PhD
```

What I want (CSV):

```
"Freddy, Jasmine, Lucy",412,Penguin
this,"5,432",salad
Joe,4,"John Smith, PhD"
```

Is there a way to do this in bash?

Comment: CSV has enough edge cases that you don't want to roll your own solution. Use a tried-and-tested CSV processing tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`csvformat`](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scripts/csvformat.html) tool from [CSVKit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) will do exactly what you want:

```
csvformat --tabs inputFile.dat
```

Example

```
printf "%s\n" \
    $'Freddy, Jasmine, and Lucy\t412\tPenguin' \
    $'Maggie\t5,432\tsalad' \
    $'Joe\t4\tJohn Smith, PhD' >inputFile.dat

csvformat --tabs inputFile.dat
```

Output

```
"Freddy, Jasmine, and Lucy",412,Penguin
Maggie,"5,432",salad
Joe,4,"John Smith, PhD"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another useful tool for this kind of thing is [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) - borrowing [@roaima's input file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/699081/65304)

```
$ mlr --itsv --ocsv cat inputFile.dat
"Freddy, Jasmine, and Lucy",412,Penguin
Maggie,"5,432",salad
Joe,4,"John Smith, PhD"
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing this with a programming language bundled with a CSV module is more verbose than csvkit or miller:

```bsh
ruby -rcsv -e '
    csvin = CSV.new(File.new(ARGV.shift), col_sep: "\t")
    csvout = CSV.new($stdout)
    csvin.each {|row| csvout.puts(row)}
' file.tsv
```

or

```bsh
ruby -rcsv -e 'CSV.foreach(ARGV.shift, col_sep: "\t") {|row| puts CSV.generate_line(row)}' file.tsv
```

outputs

```
"Freddy, Jasmine, and Lucy",412,Penguin
Maggie,"5,432",salad
Joe,4,"John Smith, PhD  "
```

Your sample data has some trailing whitespace on the last line.